# python socket server, netcat client, how can I clear netcat terminal from server

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

I have a python socket server and connecting to it via netcat, how can i clear the client's netcat terminal from server side?

Comment: You can't, unless there is a pty in place. Why do you think you would need to?

Comment: well I just wanted it just for make things look better.

Comment: If the client is a full tty or pty device (or is attached to one) then you can use ioctl to send terminal control sequences to the client. You'll probably want to use `telnet` or similar for the client rather than `netcat`. If you want a nice visual display on the client side, you should write your own client application rather than making the server do the work. You don't want to be too chatty (or latency-sensitive) across the network if you can help it.